# How to recursively turn a list of lists (base case list of strings) into a list of strings in python

Tags: python, recursion

I have objects like this:

```
values=[['MLH'], ['MLH', 'PC1_cov']]
```

That I'd like to turn into objects like this:

```
values=['MLH','MLH','PC1_cov']
```

I want to be able to accommodate lists of lists of lists, etc., etc., so I'm looking for a recursive function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that with a simple for loop:

```
values=[['MLH'], ['MLH', 'PC1_cov']]
flat = []
for val in values:
    flat += val
```

The list `flat` contains the flattened version of your original list.

Comment: This doesn't work for arbitrarily deeply nested lists, as the OP has specified.

Comment: That's right. I was concentrating on the examle he was given.